# PhpUnit @depends annotation and MockObject

Tags: php, phpunit

**This is a code example:**

```
class TestTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testFirst() {
        $factory_mock =
            $this->getMockBuilder('Factory')
                ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                ->disableOriginalClone()
                ->getMock();

        $factory_mock
            ->expects($this->any())
            ->method('getData')
            ->will($this->returnValue('123'));

        var_dump($factory_mock->getData());
        var_dump($factory_mock->getData());

    return $factory_mock;
}

    /**
     * @depends testFirst
     */
    public function testSecond(Factory $factory) {
        var_dump($factory->getData());
    }

}
```

**This is the result we get:**

```
    .string(3) "123"
    string(3) "123"
    .NULL
```

I expect the third "getData" method invocation to give me the same result as the first two, but it won't happen. I don't understand why. Please, share your knowledge about inner workings of PhpUnit.

**PHPUnit v3.7.29, PHP v5.4.23**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do a `var_dump` of your mock factory in both tests you will see that the first one has a `PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_InvocationMocker` and the in the second test that property is null.  The mocked method is being reset after the test has completed running.  So you end up with a mock that does not have its methods set.